# Node.js Asynchronous nature

Tags: node.js

Currently I am working on a real time web application for an online discussion forum. I need to include some fast unblocking access to users and I referred about node.js but I would like to have some experts' advises.  Can someone explain what is meant by **asynchronous I/O** and how it has been used in **Node.js**?

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question: [`[node.js] asynchronous i/o`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnode.js%5D+asynchronous+i%2Fo)

Comment: There are thousands of articles written about this already on the web.  You really ought to go read a bunch of those and then come back here if you have a specific question about something you don't understand.